# How to do automatic update of EXE project in C# and Azure Startup task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, exe

I am facing a critical and interesting problem in my azure related project. I have created one web application and from there a user can download a plugin (EXE project in C#) and upload EXE and config file after unzip to their application's startup taks which are deployed on Azure platform and that exe sends data periodically to my web application to monitor user application on Azure.

Now my problem is that if I make any changes in the EXE project, then how can users who have the old plugin update their files (plugin) on their existing application? I need some automatic type of update mechanism so I can avoid the conflict between old and new version of the EXE project.

I hope that my problem makes sense to you if you have some knowledge of the Azure startup task.

Thanks
Arun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure the above solution will meet several problems while trying in Windows Azure. EXE update will fail on Azure due to security issues. You would have to change the design to have such application design.

Try this:
[Will Autoupdate Startup task work in azure application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785650/will-autoupdate-startup-task-work-in-azure-application/10793980#10793980)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are providing a custom EXE to end client, which becomes part of Azure start-up task, and runs throughout the time the instance is running.

One thing that can be done is to create a self update mechanism in the EXE itself. If you have ever used [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), it has self update mechanism, where it prompts user when a new version is available. Something similar could be build. Things that you would require to keep in mind would be

1. Deciding from where updates are downloaded.
2. What happens when update location changes.
3. Any security limitations.

Also look at some vendors in this space such as Cumulux and Cerebrata on how do they do stuff.